# How to insert Java ArrayList into a MySQL table?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist

Could someone kindly tell me how can I insert the values of Arraylist into MySQL table as a single string?

E.g, insert "crime, drama, Action" into column "genres" of a table "featuredfilms_INFO".

This is a part of my code:

```
int i = 0;
List<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
.
.
.
Elements elms1 = doc.select("div.infobar"); 
Elements links1 = elms1.select("a[href]");
for (Element link1 : links1){
    if (link1.attr("href").contains("/genre/")) {
        genre.add(links1.get(i).text());
        i++;
    }
}
System.out.println("movie genres:" + genre); 
.
.
try {
     String query = "INSERT into featuredfilms_INFO (movieId, genres)" + "VALUES (?, ?)";
     PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
     preparedStmt.setString (1, ID);
     preparedStmt.setString (2, genre);
   .
   .
   .
}
```

My problem is that I cannot use `setString` for *genre* since it is not of type string. I'm a bit confused since at the beginning I defined genre as string but after some search I found that in Java for dynamic arrays I have to use `ArrayList`.

Can someone explain me in detail what should I do and why?

Comment: @JosefE. I get this ID from another table in my datbase where I stored movies.

Comment: Are you using JDBC, JPA, JDO, etc.? More information needed here

Comment: Do you want one row per genre or do you want one row with a long string containing all genres (e.g. comma separated)?

Comment: @hd1 is plain JDBC...

Comment: @ammoQ: I need all genres of each movie to be stored in one record, ex: movie1: crime, drama, then next recod: movie2: action, fantasy, history, next record: movie3: ....

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP should have indicated that in the question

Comment: @hd1 you can get it by reading the code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just join all the strings before inserting.

```
 String comma="";
 StringBuilder allGenres = new StringBuilder();
 for (String g: genre) {
    allGenres.append(comma);
    allGenres.append(g);
    comma = ", ";
 }

 String query = "INSERT into featuredfilms_INFO (movieId, genres)" + "VALUES (?, ?)";
 PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
 preparedStmt.setString (1, ID);
 preparedStmt.setString (2, allGenres.toString());
```

Maybe even

```
 preparedStmt.setString (2, genre.toString());
```

would even be good enough, but the above solution gives you more freedom how to join the genres.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :), it worked by only adding .toString() to the last line as u said

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're confused because your `List<String>` is called genre and you try to insert it as is. This won't work. You need to insert every element from the `List` in your table.

Assuming you have declared and initialized `ID` variable and that `List<String> genre` is filled with the right values, then you should only traverse the list and insert every genre:

```
String query = "INSERT into featuredfilms_INFO (movieId, genres)" + "VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setString (1, ID);
for (String realGenre : genre) {
    preparedStmt.setString (2, realGenre);
    preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: actually I summarized the insert in my question, I mean it is: INSERT into featuredfilms_INFO (movieId, genre, country)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; so now when I write your answer I get an error that "No values specified for parameter 3", and when I omit the executeUpdate line in for loop, it onnly insert the last genre for each movie !! :(
       PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

Comment: @monamona that part is outside the question, and the error is very specific: you're declaring you need to send 3 parameters but only providing 2. Provide the third parameter or remove it at all.

Comment: I provided the 3rd on, I just didnt write here. but I got the error, however it solved by only adding toString() that is:  preparedStmt.setString (2, genre.toString()); tnx anyway for your help ;)